# iOS: NSXMLParserErrorDomain Error 4, 5 & 73

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsxmlparser, grand-central-dispatch

In my application I have a `UISearchBar`, which parses the results in real-time with `NSURLConnection`, GCD and `NSXMLParser`. Everything works fine in WiFi and 3G but in EDGE I get the errors described in the title.

The parser starts right after the connection `didReceiveData`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start the parsing when connectionDidFinishLoading: is fired. In didReceiveData just concatenate the received data. See the documentation:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate

Comment: Log your xml before parsing and see if it's ok.

Comment: Solved the problem :) I set a delegate when the parser did end. Works great now. Thanks for the answer.